# I getting 401 error when using OMDb api how i can resolve this problem

Tags: reactjs, omdbapi

I am new to web development and I am trying to build a chrome extension that displays imdb scores on netflix. I am using the OMDB API to do this. At first I got the following error:

> "Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.",

however I just changed the "http" in the url to "https" and it went away. However, now I am getting a 401 error, which I think means my access is being denied. This is a picture of the full error

Here is the code for the extension

Manifest file:

Comment: Yes, that is what it was telling you the problem was. When you're on a secure page, your browser will bock insecure request, because they're (in a surprise to no one) insecure. So changing to a secure request fixed that. As for what 401 means: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401, so that's not an error, that's you either forgetting to properly authenticate (e.g. via headers or query tokens or the like), or simply not being allowed access because you don't have access.

Comment: You missed including your code